# JOOQ execution listener does not catch exception

Tags: spring, jooq

I'm trying to implement a generic solution for optimized locking. What I want to achieve is to have a specific piece of code run when record's version changes. I have it implemented as an `ExecuteListener` instance that looks for `DataChangedException`. It's registered as a Spring bean.

```kotlin
class LockingListener : DefaultExecuteListener() {

    override fun exception(ctx: ExecuteContext) {
        val exception = ctx.exception()

        if (exception is DataChangedException) {
            ctx.exception(IllegalStateException("Accessed data has been altered mid-operation."))
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Configuration
class JooqConfig {

    @Bean
    fun lockingListenerProvider() = DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(LockingListener())
}
```

I had a breakpoint set in `org.jooq.impl.ExecuteListeners#get` and it does look like it gets picked up alongside `LoggerListener` and `JooqExceptionTranslator`.

When I try to run a test case though, `DataChangedException` does not get picked up on `UpdateableRecord#update` and I get the following stacktrace instead, no `IllegalStateException` in sight.

```
org.jooq.exception.DataChangedException: Database record has been changed or doesn't exist any longer
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.checkIfChanged(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:540)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.storeMergeOrUpdate0(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:349)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.storeUpdate0(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:241)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.access$100(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:89)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl$2.operate(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:232)
    at org.jooq.impl.RecordDelegate.operate(RecordDelegate.java:149)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.storeUpdate(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:228)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.update(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:165)
```

Debugging shows that `LockingListener#exception` does not even get entered into.

Answer (score 0):

That exception is not part of  the [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html) lifecycle, i.e. the lifecycle that deals with interactions with the JDBC API. In other words, it's not a `SQLException`, it happens higher up the stack. Use the [`RecordListener.exception()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/RecordListener.html#exception(org.jooq.RecordContext)) callback, instead.